# RevTeX 4.2 : How to hide article title in bibliography citation

Tags: bibliographies, revtex, bibliographystyle

For RevTeX 4.2, the article title is now displayed by default (I believe the default journal style is `aps`) in the bibliography for all articles that are cited.

In previous versions, this used to be optional and was controlled by an option passed to the document class
`\documentclass[longbibliography]{revtex4-1}`

Is there a way to go back to this previous behaviour in version 4.2?

Answer (score 4):

`revtex4-2` provides two class options `longbibliography` and `nolongbibliography` (also found in most versions of `revtex4-1`), which cause inclusion and suppression of titles among other things (with e.g. `aps` this seems to be all, with `rmp` this also affects the inclusion of author's forenames).

Superficially, all that changed in `revtex4-2` relative to `revtex4-1` was the default switching from `nolongbibliography` to `longbibliography`.